# How GCC (libstdc++) runtime decides to terminate() while an exception is active

Tags: c++, exception, gcc, g++

We know that `terminate`()  is called if an exception is currently active and there is another call to `throw`.

Want to understand what causes this to be differentiated from a situation when a `catch` block does a `throw` from with-in? I am assuming that a if a `catch` block is executing, it signifies of an active exception.

```
class exception_type{}

try{ ... throw obj; ... 
}catch(exception_type& obj){
 ...
 ... 
 throw x;
 ...
}
```

From this code sample, since we have another `throw` here in `catch` block, which should get caught by another handler in the dynamically enclosing `try` block.
So this seems to be a valid use of a `throw` inside `catch`. But at this moment we already have a an exception active. Why should not it cause `terminate`() to be called? Or in other words, how exactly the gcc's  c++ runtime would recognize that there is already an exception active and a `terminate`() needs to be called.

Comment: I am talking about a throw in a catch block. It need not be the same exception object as originally thrown.

Comment: @VTT thanks, I tried with example this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The credit for this answer goes to @HolyBlackCat who has hinted this in his answer.

The response of a `throw` is a complex process in which C++ run-time needs to perform several distinct actions. Though the actual process may be defined by run-time's implementation but few things could be understood in common. [This paper](https://www.usenix.org/conference/wiess-2000/c-exception-handling-ia64) could shed some more light. Please see section 3.3.

In the process of servicing a `throw`, a search for appropriate `catch` is initiated. This in itself may cause unwinding of the current stack frame. The side effect of unwinding a stack frame is that corresponding destructors for objects in current frame  be called. This action of calling a destructor again lands run-time in user's code area(unsafe). After this is done, we again enter in the run-time's territory(safer).

Finally when a suitable `catch` is entered, the active exception is destroyed and it starts executing handler's code. For this reason the `throw` as shown in question, would not experience any active exception.

This also explains why we should not `throw` an exception from a destructor which goes out of scope. It would actually be a good practice to have a `try{....}catch(...)` block in destructor to safeguard from any untoward `terminate`() incidents.

Answer (score 1):

An exception stops being 'active' as soon as it's `catch`ed (when control enters a `catch` section).

Comment: Thanks +1, I could now recollect the detail from paper "C++ Exception Handling for IA-64" Would you mind if I explain this in my own answer to question with elaboration.

Comment: @ultimatecause Sure, I don't mind. It's *your* question after all.